Problem with SPL Token accounts TokenAccountNotFoundError
I am trying to transfer some SPL tokens from X wallet to Y.
const key = new web3.PublicKey(
            'bSo13r4TkiE4KumL71LsHTPpL2euBYLFx6h9HP3piy1',
          );
          const fromTokenAccount =
            await splToken.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
              connection,
              solWallet.payer,
              key,
              solWallet.publicKey,
            );

          const toTokenAccount =
            await splToken.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
              connection,
              nextSolWallet.payer,
              key,
              nextSolWallet.publicKey,
            );


Now the problem is when the code is ran, it results in a TokenAccountNotFoundError on the first line (getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount)
What I checked

The wallet arguments are right (checked with a debugger)
The key is also right https://solscan.io/token/bSo13r4TkiE4KumL71LsHTPpL2euBYLFx6h9HP3piy1
Checked a few threads, Solana documentations and my code is very similar other than variable names.

solWallet & nextSolWallet
const solWallet = new Wallet(
          Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(wallet.privateKey)),
        );
        const nextSolWallet = new Wallet(
          Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(nextWallet.privateKey)),
        );



If you've just created your mint, you might need to wait for the transaction to land on-chain. Be sure to use the confirmed commitment with your connection, and make sure to confirm previous transactions before moving on to creating the associated token accounts.
